# Creating second prompt in Js function

Tags: javascript, function, nan, prompt

First post here. :) I am creating my first program using Js, and I’m stumped on figuring out an error prompt. Here is my code so far:

```
  let number = +prompt("Enter a number!", "");
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log(`${number} / ${i} = ${number / i}`);
  }
  if (number == NaN) {
    return
    let number = +prompt("Hundy Says: \"I can only do magical things with numbers! Please enter a number!\"");
      for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      console.log(`${number} / ${i} = ${number / i}`);
    }
}
  else {
  return number;
  }
}

hundyDivide();
```

I want the program to run so that if a user enters NaN or nothing at all, it returns a prompt asking the user for a number. When I run this code, it returns NaN / 1 = NaN…NaN / 100 = NaN.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `NaN !== NaN`, due to IEEE754. You have to use e.g. `isNaN`, or [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN). Note, that this by itself won't fix your program, but is part of the issue.

Comment: `if (number == NaN) { return` will stop the function there, so `let number = /*...*/` will not run.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you!